# Are "zombie" tags removed on meta, too?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I know that on main site the tags which have no questions associated to them are removed from the system every 24 hours, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags) or [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/how-liberally-should-we-handle-tag-creation/2829#2829).

However, we have a few tags at meta which have no question. A few examples: [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close), [votes](/questions/tagged/votes), [login](/questions/tagged/login), [data-dump](/questions/tagged/data-dump), [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags). (Situation might change later, but you can find out whether we have such tags simply displaying tags by popularity and going to the [last page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags?page=4&tab=popular).)

These tags are empty but they do exist in the system in the sense that they are between suggestions when you tag a question, you are also offered a possibility to create a wiki, when you display the tag, etc. Compare with a tag that really does not exist: [abcdefgh](/questions/tagged/abcdefgh).

Here are screenshots (as of June 24, 2012):

[image: vote-to-close]

[image: abcdefgh]

> So I was curious whether empty tags are pruned at meta, not only at main. And if they are, how often does this happen?

**EDIT**: I guess this question might be more appropriate for [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), so perhaps in a few days I'll try to search meta.SO once again and if I don't find anything related to this there, I'll ask there. (One of the reasons I've posted the questions here was that I was not able to find examples of such tags at meta.SO.)

Comment: Some tags are imported from Meta.SO to all child metas, I suspect that those are examples for that, explaining why they're not deleted.

Comment: @MadScientist This would explain that, all of the above tags are mentioned this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62655/add-a-selection-of-default-tags-to-all-metas
Perhaps you could post your comment as an answer.

Comment: BTW I've asked a related question at meta.SO:
[What are the differences between tag pruning on main sites and their metas?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138103/what-are-the-differences-between-tag-pruning-on-main-sites-and-their-metas)